# Placing & deleting element(s) from a object (stack)

Tags: c#

Initializing 2 stack objects:

```
Stack s1 = new Stack(), s2 = new Stack();
```

s1 = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (array of 10 elements which is empty to start with) top:0

```
        const int Rows = 10;
    int[] Table = new int[Rows];

    public void TableStack(int[] Table)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < Table.Length; i++)
        {
        }
    }
```

My question is how exactly do I place a element on a stack (push) or take a element from the stack (pop) as the following:
**Push:**

```
s1.Push(5);   // s1 = 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   (top:1)
s1.Push(9);   // s1 = 5 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   (top:2)
```

**Pop:**

```
int number = s1.Pop();  // s1 = 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (top:1) 9 got removed
```

Do I have to use get & set, and if so how exactly do I implement this with a array?
Not really sure what to exactly use for this.
Any hints highly appreciated.

The program uses the following driver to test the Stack class (which cannot be changed or modified):

```
        public void ExecuteProgram()
    {
        Console.Title = "StackDemo";
        Stack s1 = new Stack(), s2 = new Stack();
        ShowStack(s1, "s1");
        ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        Console.WriteLine();
        int getal = TryPop(s1);
        ShowStack(s1, "s1");
        TryPush(s2, 17);
        ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        TryPush(s2, -8);
        ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        TryPush(s2, 59);
        ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            TryPush(s1, 2 * i);
            ShowStack(s1, "s1");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            TryPush(s2, i * i);
            ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            getal = TryPop(s2);
            //use number

            ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        }
    }/*ExecuteProgram*/
```

Comment: Why not use a small wrapper around List<> ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built in `Stack<T>` which will give you push, pop, peek etc.

Comment: I dont want to use a build in stack class for this.
Thanks though.

Comment: @Chris: if your homework assignment says you can't use the built-in class then you need to state so in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack object has Push and Pop methods on it.  Simply call s1.Push and s1.Pop exactly as you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you need to maintain the index of the topmost element in your internal array in the `Stack` class.

I’m not sure what you mean by get/set but chances are, you don’t need that here (in particular if you actually meant properties).

Comment: Yeah i ment properties.
Was making something similar the other day and it was getting me confused if i should use those or not.